# Meteor.js: template.<html>.events vs Template.<template>.events 'this' binding seems inconsistent

Tags: meteor, binding, meteor-blaze

I'm looking through the Meteor simple tutorial and the way that 'this' binding in the different Template objects works seems inconsistent to me in my unknowledgeable state.

```
Template.body.events({
    "submit .new-task": function(event) {
        console.log(this); // Logs an empty object
    }
})


Template.task.events({
     "click .toggle-checked": function() {
         console.log(this); // logs a task
     }   
});
```

I can see that task is an xml template defined in the view, which is a visual representation of the items returned by a function in the `Template.body.helpers` object.

I guess that the task objects are bound the html representation of each object (though I can't see how as there doesn't seem to be any identifying property within the `li` elements??)

**Anyhow. When I click the task, `this` is the task. But when I submit the form, I was expecting `this` to be the body. Why is it not?**

I was expecting Meteor to handle `Template.body` and `Template.task` in a similar way

Comment: In events, `this` is simply the current data context of the template. I would not expect `body` to have a data context, so therefore `this` is empty. Not sure you mean with "`this` to be the body". What would that be? the html of the body?

Comment: What do you mean by data context? I would have thought that just the dom element would be 'this' in general, but with the task it looks like it is first getting 'reglued' back to the data that was initially pulled from the collection. The reason I would have thought 'body' not to be an empty object is because I would have imagined Meteor to add metadata to all DOM nodes and hold those in the model. But on second thoughts I can't think why I thought that was necessary...

Comment: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/

Comment: That looks helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Meteor `this` referes to the data context. You define it with helpers or with the route controller ( IronRouter or FlowRouter)

Example:

```
{{#with myData}}
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
{{/with}}
```

js

```
Template.yourTemplate.helpers({
    myData : function(){
        return {
            title : "My title" 
        }
    }
})
```

You need to use the "event" argument

```
Template.task.events({
     "click .toggle-checked": function( event , instance ) {
         console.log( event );
     }   
});
```

The instance argument is also very useful. You have access to a jQuery selector like: `instance.$()` and it will only search for elements on your template and also child templates.

Personally I use the instance a lot. My Favorite pattern is:

```
Template.task.onCreated(function(){
    this.vars = new ReactiveDict();
    this.data = "some data";
});
```

Later if you want to access `vars` or `data`:

- Events - You get this on the arguments
- Helpers - `var instance = Template.instance();`

With instance you avoid storing states in the global namespace, like Session, and your code is a lot easier to maintain and understand. I hope this helps you to understand how template works in Blaze.

Comment: I'm just getting started on Meteor so I haven't come across the route controller yet, and not too sure what a data-context is yet. Thanks for the answer